# Create constructor for different go structs

Tags: go

I have a struct which I initiate in some process like following, and this is working as expected.

**This is specific runner**

```
type TestRunner struct {
    path string
    name string
}

func NewRunner(p string, n string) *TestRunner {
    return &TestRunner{
        path: p,
        name: n,
    }
}
```

Now I want in the same package to create another runner so I do it like this e.g.

**Also specific runner**

```
type TestRunner2 struct {
    path string
    name string
}

func NewRunner(p string, n string) *TestRunner2 {
    return &TestRunner2{
        path: p,
        name: n,
    }
}
```

Now I get error that the func `NewRunner` is exist

I have another file (in the same package) which include the interface

**This is generic implementation** (different file in the same package)

```
type Runner interface {
    Run(path string) error         
    ChangePath(newPath string) 
}
```

So maybe the NewRunner should be there, where its recommended to put the new object ?

obviously I can create `NewRunner1` and `NewRunner2` method in the file but im not sure if it’s recommended

Comment: Why the need for two structs with same fields?

Comment: I'd say they should be named `NewTestRunner1` and `NewTestRunner2`.

Comment: you can use receivers for same name functions to implement in same file

Comment: What exactly is your question? You clearly understand the error, and you've proposed a solution. Are you just asking if your solution (two separate functions) is acceptable? (It is)

Comment: @Flimzy - Since Im not expert in GO and I want to verify the direction I've ask this question? would you suggest something else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should name your runners according to their functionality, not by number.  `FastRunner` and `SlowRunner` or `LocalRunner` vs `RemoteRunner`.  You get the idea.  Then you should create a construct for each one:

```
func NewFastRunner( ... ) *FastRunner {
    return &FastRunner{ ... }
}

func NewSlowRunner( ... ) *SlowRunner {
    return &SlowRunner{ ... }
}
```

This is standard practice, and makes for very readable, unambiguous code.

Comment: The return type should generally be the concrete type though, so callers get access to specific methods and fields without type assertions.

Comment: @Peter - can you give example of what do you mean ?  should it be like `func NewRunner1(p string, n string) *TestRunner2 {
    return &TestRunner2{
        path: p,
        name: n,
    }
}`

Comment: @Flimzy - thanks, btw, when you suggest to use factory than? if I need to support different version or ?

Comment: The Factory pattern rarely makes sense in Go. Do you have an example of a use case that isn't met with a simple constructor method?

Comment: @Flimzy - Yes for example if I need to create NewFastRunner that support more then one version of this fast runner,each version can have different logic inside...

Answer (score -1):

You can use method pointer type receivers for each runner and then implement interface. That way you need not to return any thing you can directly assign values like path and name to runner using pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TestRunner1 struct {
    path string
    name string
}

type TestRunner2 struct {
    path string
    name string
}

type Runner interface {
    Run(path string) error
    ChangePath(newPath string)
}

func (tr1 *TestRunner1) NewRunner(p string, n string) {
    tr1.path = p
    tr1.path = n
}

func (tr2 *TestRunner2) NewRunner(p string, n string) {
    tr2.path = p
    tr2.path = n
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Check the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/roKHXW7GJhH)

Comment: Convention is that a method called `NewX` should return an instance of `X`, not be a receiver for `X`.

Comment: @Flimzy we cannot create two methods with same name using interface without having different method receivers that's why the error `NewRunner` is exist. I have given my solution on basis of error received too

Comment: @Flimzy - How would you do it ?

Comment: @JennyHilton: With two different constructors.

Comment: @Flimzy - Like  `NewTestRunner1` and `NewTestRunner2 ` in there owne file ?

Comment: @JennyHilton: Yes. But whether they are in a single file or separate files is irrelevant. I'd also consider using more descriptive names. Why do you have two runners? Name the runners according to their functionality, rather than by number.   `NewFastRunner` and `NewSlowRunner` (or whatever) is a lot better.

Comment: @Flimzy - can you provide it as answer and i'll close the question ?

Comment: so if there are multiple runners we have to create constructor for each. Are we serious that can be redundant code. @Flimzy please provide a solution. I am in learning phase. I also wants to see best approach

Comment: @Himanshu: Yes, of course I'm serious. There's no other reasonable way. And "bulky code" (whatever that means) isn't a problem, if the code serves a purpose.

Comment: constructor should be created according to functionality not on basis of object names

Comment: @Himanshu: Object names should be created according to functionality. If you have only a single functionality, you should have only a single object type, and thus a single name. If you have two object types, you obviously have two functionalities, so you should have two names, and two constructors.